# How to edit a tag using javascript after loading html into a div from a different file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my index file, I'm trying to load a Bootstrap modal from another html file into a div. After loading, I'm editing the header of that modal using javascript. But that text is not changing on the First load but later, The text changing is working fine. Is there any way to Load the html from other file, then execute the javascript. I'm editing the text using ID from other html file.

Here is my JavaScript

```
function changeTypeName(){

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'adminAnchor'){
            alert('admin');
            document.getElementById('userType').innerHTML= "Login (Admin)";

        }
        else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'examinerAnchor'){
            document.getElementById('userType').innerHTML= "Login (Examiner)";
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML where I'm trying to load the Bootstrap modal after clicking an anchor tag then Edit the text after loading .

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="adminAnchor" href="loginModal.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#indexModal">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a id="examinerAnchor" href="loginModal.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#indexModal">Examiner</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(changeTypeName);
    alert(changeTypeName);
</script>
```

I'm load the modal into this div from other HTML file.

```
<div id="indexModal" class="modal fade text-center" >
<div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the Bootstrap modal from different class.

```
<div class="modal-header text-center">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h3 class="modal-title" id="userType">Login</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body " style="margin: auto">
    <!--some FORM here -->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <!--Some text and button here-->
</div>
```

Here On the first execution of Javascript, Html file and the ID is not present in the index file but later working fine because html tags and Id of modal from other file is present in the index file.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you provide a complete code sample? I'm not sure what you're actually doing. For example: where is the javascript embedded? How do you load the other HTML file?

Comment: Here is the index file link: http://codepen.io/i_love_sabin/pen/dMdoPK
and login Modal link: http://codepen.io/i_love_sabin/pen/LNQVNm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the dom is completely loaded, that is why you should put your click into the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(changeTypeName);
});
```

instead of

```
$("a").click(changeTypeName);
```

Regards!

Comment: There is a space in the 2nd code sample, you may want to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this is not working for me :( I've provided link of my code in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You should change your javascript to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click","a",changeTypeName);
    alert(changeTypeName);
</script>
```

And perhaps move it to the bottom of the page. after the modal window code.

Answer (score 0):

only when the document gets loaded you should call the `on click` event.

```
$(function() {
   $("a").on('click',changeTypeName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're modal is in a separate .html golw than your li and a elements && you are attempting to load it dynamically into file...

You will need to asyncronously lod that file's contents then write it in using the

ELEMENT.innerHTML   property...

Check out asynchronous [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)